# Autofit row height in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Using Excel 2007.  Attempting to insert photo in each row and a specific column, but when the picture is inserted the row doesn't adjust to the height of the photo. I've tried selecting the row and selecting format Autofit row height, but even using a very small one, the picture spills down over the 8 or so rows below the selected row.  The row makes no adjustment.  I think I'm not getting some basic set up issue.  I've never been trained on this product, so I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is because pictures don't count as cells, but instead objects above the sheet. The easiest work around is to adjust the row and column to the picture. 
Hopefully the pictures are the same size so you can just highlight all rows and columns (click the button at the corner of column A and Row 1) then drag one of the rows to match your image size. You can now paste into this opening.

You might also consider formatting the image to size and move with the cells for easier editing. Do this by right clicking the image and choosing format picture, then choosing Properties, and "Move and size with cells."

Add-Ins:
This may not be what you want, but there is an auto add-in for this process if you have to do this photo add frequently. It does what you directly want with a special toolbar function. 
http://excel-image-assistant.com/